# How can I prevent other sites from linking to my javascript files?

Tags: php, javascript, apache

I have some jquery plugins hosted on my server, but I'd like it to be available only to my visitors.. I'm paranoid other websites might just link to my js files and steal my bandwidth.
How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Why do they need to link to your site? They can very well download them when viewing your site and use it right??

Comment: If i were to use your plugins, i'd better download that javascript file (if you allow me to) as who knows - you may rename your file, change functionality or do some other things that would break my site.

Comment: Someone might eat up some of your bandwidth; but, linking to your javascript will not enable them to steal your traffic.  In fact, if you craft your javascript right, you can steal their traffic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use your .htaccess file to restrict the domain.

- [Selective hotlinking prevention through .htaccess](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629002749/http://underscorebleach.net/jotsheet/2004/06/htaccess-prevent-hotlinking)
- [Prevent Hotlinking of Image, Script, CSS etc Using .htaccess](https://web.archive.org/web/20111007200136/http://www.globinch.com/2011/04/13/prevent-hotlinking-of-image-script-css-etc-using-htaccess)

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: @swalog: Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Cretae a .htaccess in the root of you site folder (for apache or IIS with ISAPI_Rewrite)

Replace mysite.com with your domain remebering that all . have to be backslashed in the RewriteCond and replace with a page you want to send them to when there trying to steal your bandwidth

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\. (js|json)$ http://mysite.com/theif.txt
```

and add theif.txt to your site with the code below (any site trying to steal your code will send all there users to http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/bandwidththeft.html lol

`top.location = "http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/bandwidththeft.html";`

They will soon unlink your script from there page

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to prevent them using your javascript files directly, but there is no guaranteed way to prevent them from copying your files and use them manually, i can already see few answers you may want to try this:

- use your javascript files by a php file:

  ```
  header("content-type: text/javascript");
  if(isset($_GET["name"]) && strpos("yourdomain.com", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
       echo(file_get_contents("hidden_path_to_js/".$_GET["js_name"]."js"));
  else
       die("access denied");
  ```

In above sample you going to check if refer address is your website or not, so for using your js file

```
<script src="get_js_file.php?js_name=jquery"></script>
```

Comment: @Webnat0 I think you will be able to cache with adding few more headers: header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2011 05:00:00 GMT");

Comment: just for the Expires thing when out puting it use the `date()` function to write the exact time and date more what i think @Pezhvak IMV was thinking

Answer (score 1):

you could always run the javascript through a PHP file using .htaccess to route all requests to it. If the user-agent is different from your website, then it can send a 403, otherwise it could use a file_get_contents to return the file.

hope that helps

useful htaccess template:
    CheckSpelling on
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymlinks

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /js/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why would you use .htaccess to send them to a php file that has to do more work then just sending them to a file that prevents them using your script?

Comment: dunno, didn't think of it. but i use it because i can upload a javascript file into it, then the php file minifies and packs it. plus it has a tracker in it to prevent the same file being loaded twice or during a single instance.